# How to use Ruby on Rails 3.2 with 'yui 3.5'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yui

I'm writing write my first RoR application with YUI framework. I tried googling for ror+yui manuals with no success. So I went to YUI site. [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/quick-start/) says:

```
// Put the YUI seed file on your page.
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

Where it's supposed to be putted in RoR app?

I've tried to `app/assert/javascripts/yui-min.js`.

As a result i got `<html class="yui3-js-enabled">` in every page. Supposing YUI is working now i've tried to copy-paste "*Work with the DOM*" example from [YUI's page](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/quick-start/) to `app/public/index.html`.

The error I received was:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: YUI is not defined`.

I tried the info in this link and it was not helpful to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452829/tutorial-suggestions-on-yui-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step in any rails app is to delete app/public/index.html ... then work in your pages inside of rails.

So that means create an app/views/layouts/application.html, and that's where you add your

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

Based on the link, you might not have it in your `<head>` and it needs to be.

UPDATE: (sample javascript code to change h1)

```
<script>
    YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
      var headerElement     = Y.one('h1');
      headerElement.setHTML("I have been updated");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No `Uncaught ReferenceError: YUI is not defined` now and no changes at the page. Tried to do that within `app/views/modelname/index.html.erb` by inserting "Work with the DOM" script from [YUI link] in my post.

Comment: You'll probably need to post the layout and index HTML/ERB

Comment: Please also add app/views/layouts/application.html

Comment: OK, the sample YUI code is just that, sample -- I can't see how it would actually make changes to the HTML. I'll update answer with sample code that will change the H1